# Is there anyway to restore a deleted graphdb repository?

Tags: graphdb

Mistakenly I have deleted a repository from live https://graphdb.sti2.at/ , Is there anyway that I can restore the deleted graphdb repository ? Its important to restore.

Comment: You could restore deleted repository from backup, if you have one.

Comment: @SavaSavov I have backup from server , do you know how can I restore deleted repo from server backup ?

Answer (score 0):

For properly recover deleted repository from backup, follow the instructions given in our documentation:
https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/backing-up-and-recovering-repo.html?highlight=restoring%20repository%20from%20backup#restore-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

[Sava Savovs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65107786/3330861) is correct, but there is one step missing for

"*Option 2: Restore the database from a binary image or zip backup.*"

Step 1 should be the same as for Option 1:

**Make sure that the repository is empty or recreated with the same repository configuration settings.**

I wrote Ontotext to fix this.